# How common is it for large objects (few kilometers wide) in a young protoplanetary disk or debris disk to collide with one another?

Tags: astrophysics, collision, protostar, space-debris, proto-planetary-disk

If enough time has passed for gravitational forces to allow the formation of planetesimals(proto-planets) in orbit around the proto-star, how likely is it that two of them would collide with one another? If they do collide, would a head-on collision be more likely than a glancing collision?

What would be the observable effect of such a phenomena?

Comment: How do you understand that “gravitational forces” are responsible for the formation of planetesimals? It sounds ambiguous because both star–planetesimal and planetesimal–planetesimal forces can be assumed in that statement.

Comment: I apologize if the question wasn't clear enough. Since the assumption states that enough time has passed for a proto-sun to be formed, I would suppose both the forces (star-planetesimal and planetesimal-planetesimal) would act. In that case, what are the chances that two proto-planets in orbit would collide? Head-on or otherwise?

Comment: The “head-on” label makes no quantitative sense without specific threshold. An ideal head-on collision has probability 0. Every practical collision brings or takes some angular momentum for the bodies involved.